# Using Git submodules in Gitlab CI jobs

Tags: git, gitlab

#### Summary

Git submodules dont work in CI jobs

#### Steps to reproduce

- Create a file **.gitmodules**

  `[submodule "database_schema"]
  path = database_schema
  url = ../../nss/database_schema.git`
- My **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

rspec:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - ls
    - cd database_schema
```

```

#### What is the current *bug* behavior?

I cant acces to my submodule repo inside ci job.

`$ cd database_schema
/bin/bash: line 63: cd: database_schema: No such file or directory`

But i can see the line **Upating/initializing submodules recursively.** in my job

`Fetching changes...
Checking out e5ed3c03 as master...
Updating/initializing submodules recursively...
Checking cache for master...
Successfully extracted cache`